# Android PDF Writer is ignoring my views heights when WRAP_CONTENT

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Androids built in PDF writer, but it's ignoring the height of my views that use wrap content and truncating the text on width and height.

When I add a fixed height though, 300dp, it can show the whole content.

In my case the content is all dynamic, very basic html, I can't use a fixed height on my layout.  I also don't want to be loading it into a webview as it'll be simple html.

I've tried writing the rootview, as well as the textview, and both behave the same.

Is there any way to do this and use wrap content?

I've attached images for both.

```
fun printDocument() {
    var printAttributes =
        PrintAttributes.Builder().setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR)
            .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER)
            .setResolution(Resolution("zooey", Context.PRINT_SERVICE, 2000, 2000))
            .setMinMargins(Margins(25, 25, 25, 25)).build()

    var document = PrintedPdfDocument(this, printAttributes)

    var page = document.startPage(0)

    val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

    textView.text =
            "this is a silly problem\nand really annoying\nvery annoying"

    textView.draw(page.canvas);

    document.finishPage(page);

    val file = File(filesDir, "myPdf.pdf")
    val outputStream = file.outputStream()

    document.writeTo(outputStream)

    document.close()
    outputStream.close()
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootview"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Print" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Wrap Content on TextView

[image]

300dp on Textview

[image]

Comment: (responding to deleted comment re: requestLayout) That's it kinda... request layout doesn't work, but you're right that it's not had a chance to resize it yet as hard coding the text in the view worked.  I put it in a coroutine with a delay after the requestlayout, and voila it works.  Is there some way to do this though without adding a delay like that?

Comment: Yeah, after I'd posted that, I realized that `setText()` would already be calling `requestLayout()`, so that was pointless. The only other thing that came to mind immediately was the delay, but that's kinda hacky, so I didn't want to suggest that, either.

Comment: Technically this all has to be done just before a network call once a button is pressed... It's already going to trigger an async call with a wait for success notification, so it's hacky but it'd work... I'm open to other suggestions if anyone has one.

Comment: Actually, if you put the draw and subsequent stuff in a `Runnable`, and `post()` it on the `TextView` after setting the text, I would think it should be queued to happen right after the layout, without having to guess at an appropriate delay.

Comment: That worked!  textview.post() after setting the text with the draw stuff inside the runnable.  If you add an answer for that I'll mark it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that the `TextView` was not getting a chance to lay itself out again, and resize to fit the new text, before the `draw()` call happened after setting that text.

Though we found that incorporating a slight delay before the draw would work, that's kinda hacky, as we're really just guessing at an appropriate interval.

Instead, we can queue the draw and subsequent operations to occur right after the layout, by moving the `draw()` and following calls into a `Runnable`, and calling `post()` on the `TextView` with that after setting the text.